# What does 'modules linked in' mean in call trace?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

In a call trace we see:

```
WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 123456 at xxxxxxxx
Modules linked in: cmac md4 cifs ccm ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 xt_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack ip6table_filter iptable_filter bridge stp llc cdc_acm i2c_mux_ltc4306 i2c_mux cdc_ether usbnet mii amd64_edac_mod edac_mce_amd edac_core xhci_pci gq(O) kvm_amd pcspkr sha3_generic xhci_hcd i2c_piix4 evdev acpi_cpufreq sch_fq_codel i2c_via_ipmi(O) autofs4

Call trace:
xxxxxxxx
```

What do the `Modules linked in` mean?
Does it mean the modules related to ( or called from?) this call trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Modules linked in” lists all the modules currently loaded, along with their taint flags if any. If modules have been loaded and then unloaded, the last unloaded module is listed too. If any modules are being loaded or unloaded, they are marked with `+` or `-` respectively.

The list isn’t limited to modules involved in the trace.

See [the kernel bug-hunting guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/bug-hunting.html#modules-linked-in) for details.